# How to update Weblogic and JDK on Windows platform?

Tags: java, weblogic, java-6

I have exist weblogic and JDK old versions on Windows platform. I want to update them. But when I search document about update steps on internet, I couldn't find anything. They just mention about installing process.(I know how to installing on systems but I  don't want to delete and re-install).

So I really want to see step by step updates. Anyone can share doc or link about it?

Comment: Can you give versions you are upgrading from and to ?

Comment: weblogic 10.3 to 12.2.1 and jdk1.6.0_31-R28.2.3-4.1.0 to jdk 1.8 ty emmanuel

Comment: Oracle WebLogic Server upgrade guide : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLUPG/index.html

Comment: ty @Emmanuel Collin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**7 STEPS as below to do upgrade weblogic 1036 from JDK6 to JDK7**

1. Install JDK 7;
2. Stop all processes that use the your MW_HOME.
3. Edit $MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/commEnv.sh and change the JAVA_HOME location.
4. For every domain, change the domain "setDomainEnv.sh" script to accomodate for the net JAVA_HOME .
5. Change the JDK location specified in nodemanager.properties for the default and any other existing nodemanager process
6. Replace the new JDK location on all the minor tools used in the same MW_HOME, such as BSU, uninstaller, etc.
7. Restart the processes as normal, they should take the new JDK version.

Please refer to [this](http://akhilesh-humbe.blogspot.hk/2012/10/upgrade-jdk-used-by-oracle-weblogic.html) for more details.